# extract only regex path-pattern from line of data

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression

Given looping over this data set, what's the most concise method to extract only the '/path/file' pattern? (excluding the library name and memory address).

```
ldd /bin/bash
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe4e1a5000)
        libtinfo.so.6 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007fb4d07de000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb4d05da000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb4d0205000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb4d0d25000)
```

My `sed/regex` is shamefully weak. I've seen a few other Stack Overflow answers but they all seem a bit off; either including something in addition to the pattern or the expression works on the Unix version of `sed` and not the GNU one.

Comment: is your input just a text file?

Comment: no, it's a very laborious script but for the sake of simplicity, this one part would be okay to test in a text file. The rest is:
1) takes a path as the $1 argument; /bin for example
2) runs find on that directory to find any binaries
3) when a binary is found, ldd is run against it
4) extract paths from ldd output (above)
5) copy the identified libraries to a directory structure like where it was found

Answer (score 3):

I was able to accomplish what I think you want using `grep` with extended regex:

```
ldd /bin/bash | grep -oE '(\/.+?) '
```

grep is looking for a literal `/` followed by anything (non-greedy) `.+?` up to any whitespace

```
$ ldd /bin/bash | grep -oE '(\/.+?) '
/lib64/libtinfo.so.5
/lib64/libdl.so.2
/lib64/libc.so.6
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Comment: `ldd /bin/bash | grep -oE '\/.*(!? )' ` +1

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Hah, I'm on mac so the command wasn't found.  Executing on a linux machine and updating

Comment: Mac too, with a Debian VM. ;)

Comment: Yeah, the macOS otool part went down fast and easy; ldd was all over the place though.

Comment: And - DAYM - that's the super-model of regex. Simple, graceful and skinny as hell. @Jesse_b, thank you.

Comment: You do not need the () - `grep -oE '\/.*!? '`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro:  I believe that will match the space as well though (At least it does on regex101.com)

Comment: @Jesse_b True,  `od -a` shows the spaces.